# Issue Using Integrating Factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, integrating-factor

Let $F(x)$ be an arbitrary continuously differentiable function, and consider the following differential equation

$$ y'+ \frac{F'(x)}{F(x)}y= \frac{1}{F(x)}.$$

If I use the [Integrating Factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor) which says that for an equation
$$ y'+ P(x)y= Q(x),$$

the general solution is

$$ y=e^{-\int P(x)dx}\int Q(x)e^{\int P(x)dx}dx+Ce^{-\int P(x)dx}.$$

Using the fact that

$$\int \frac{F'(x)}{F(x)} dx = \ln(F(x)), $$

this simplifies to

$$ y=(1+C)F(x)^{-1}.$$

However, if I substitute this solution into the initial differential equation I get

$$ -\frac{(1+C)F'(x)}{F(x)^2} + \frac{F'(x)}{F(x)}\frac{(1+C)}{F(x)} = \frac{1}{F(x)}, $$

or

$$ 0 = \frac{1}{F(x)}. $$

Where is my mistake?

Comment: $\int 1 \neq 1$

Comment: Rewrite the differential equation as $(y'F+F'y)=1$ and note that the LHS is $(yF)'$.

Comment: Your solution for y is not correct. That's why when you plug it in the DE it gives you something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need an integrating factor:
$$y'+ \frac{F'(x)}{F(x)}y= \frac{1}{F(x)}$$
$$F(x)y'+ F'(x)y= 1 $$
$$(F(x)y)'= 1$$
$$F(x)y= x+c$$
$$ \implies y(x)= \dfrac {\color{blue}{x+c}}{F(x)}$$
And not $y(x)= \dfrac {\color{red}{1+c}}{F(x)}$

---

$$y=e^{-\int P(x)dx}\int Q(x)e^{\int P(x)dx}dx+Ce^{-\int P(x)dx}.$$
$$y=\dfrac {1}{F(x)}\int dx+\dfrac C{F(x)}$$
$$y=\dfrac {x}{F(x)}+\dfrac C{F(x)}$$

Comment: In the first step, you are using $F$ as integrating factor, you multiply the equation with it to get integrable expressions. You are just not using the formula for it.

Comment: Yes that's true @LutzLehmann I just multiplied the equation by $F(x)$ Then I integrated the DE.